# Win32 API console cursor not moving after WriteConsole

Tags: c++, c++11, winapi

So, when I try to read a std::wstring from the console with this code

```
std::wstring string;
wchar_t c;
DWORD u;
do {
    ReadConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &c, 1, &u, NULL);
} while (u && (c == L' ' || c == L'\n'));
do {
    string.append(1, c);
    ReadConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &c, 1, &u, NULL);
} while (u && c != L' ' && c != L'\n');

WriteConsole(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), string.data(), string.length(), &u, NULL);
```

After writing the string the cursor position does not move and so if I call again WriteConsole(), it will write above the just written string.
Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Why are you using `ReadConsole()` instead of `std::cin >> string;`? And why are you using `WriteConsole()` instead of `std::cout << string;`? Everything you are doing manually, standard C++ I/O already handles for you.

Comment: What you describe is not how [`WriteConsole()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) is documented to work: "*The WriteConsole function writes characters to the console screen buffer at the current cursor position. **The cursor position advances as characters are written.** The SetConsoleCursorPosition function sets the current cursor position.*"

Comment: I’m writing a wrapper to WinAPI console functions and I do not want to use C++ I/O. Yeah, exactly, the problem is that the cursor does not advance.

Comment: This is because the string in `string.data()` ends with `\r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `ReadConsole` reads stdin, it will append `\r\n` to the string. You have only excluded `\n` in the conditio. `"string\r"` will be passed to `WriteConsole`, and `\r` will return the cursor to the beginning of the line.
Try the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::wstring string;
    wchar_t c;
    DWORD u;
    do {
        ReadConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &c, 1, &u, NULL);
    } while (u && (c == L' ' || c == L'\n'));
    do {
        string.append(1, c);
        ReadConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE), &c, 1, &u, NULL);
    } while (u && c != L' ' && c != L'\n' && c != L'\r');

    WriteConsoleW(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), string.data(), string.length(), &u, NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi,@Mattia Gregnanin does this solve your issue? please feel free to let me if you have any problem